# Why does clearRect not work on html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have tried a simple animation of text on canvas. However it does not clear the canvas whenever i press animate again. clearRect() function is not working properly.

here is the code:

```
document.getElementById('click').onclick = function() {

 var startTime = new Date().getTime();
 var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (new Date().getTime() - startTime > 2000) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.width);

    animateText();
  }, 33);

}
```

Here is the **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anish_jana/9tufsevL/9/)**

Should animate from beginning(the first instance) everytime I click animate button.

Comment: Please include the `animateText` function too.

Comment: basically, it does clear the context, the thing is you probably have the text animation running when you click it => the text gets drawn again.

Answer (score 0):

Your screen ***is*** being cleared, its just that you didn't reset any value, like `distance` and `speed`. Also, keep in mind that you are creating a new `interval` every time you click the button (since you are using `var` ).

So, you'll need to reset the values every click, and remove `var`.

Additionally, your `clearInterval(interval);` seems to be slightly delayed... So try that every button click.

```
document.getElementById('click').onclick = function() {

 var startTime = new Date().getTime();
 clearInterval(interval); //clearinterval
 distance = 0; //reset values
 speed = 15; //reset values
 interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (new Date().getTime() - startTime > 2000) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.width);

    animateText();
  }, 33);

}
```